# A good place to find frameworks with Interface Builder plug-ins…

Tags: cocoa, macos, plugins, interface-builder

Someone on here recently recommended BWToolkit, and it really impressed me, so I started googling for more IB plug-ins. I've found a couple on random blogs, but haven't been able to find any kind of repository/aggregator for them. Anyone know where I can find more of these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just created [a page on CocoaDev to list them](http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?InterfaceBuilderPlugins) [edit: question originally just said “Interface Builder plug-ins”, did not mention Cocoa frameworks], with the two I know of listed.

Comment: I added Cocoa frameworks because Interface Builder plug-ins are just a point of integration between Interface Builder and Cocoa frameworks.  Without a framework, what would you have to plug in to IB?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a good start. I guess that wiki page is the de-facto repository, for now. Seems like there's not much out there.

Comment: There's actually quite a bit out there - Sparkle, TouchCode, DarkKit & BGHUDAppKit, Blocks, GData-Objective-C, iMedia, TDParseKit, TCMPortMapper, MGTwitterEngine, XMPPFramework, PLDatabase, OCMock, LJKit, Log4Cocoa, JRSwizzle, Growl...  They're frameworks, though, not "IB plug-ins."

Comment: Many of those are NOT IB plugins. I am not looking for plain old frameworks. Please stop trying to change my question. If you have answers, post a response.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for Interface Builder plug-ins.  You think you are, but you aren't.  BWToolkit, the example you use in your question, is **not** an Inteface Builder plug-in.  Brandon *bills it* as an Interface Builder plug-in but it is actually a framework *and* a plug-in.  The framework contains the actual controls.  The plug-in contains the integration with Interface Builder.

So really, what you are looking for are frameworks that **contain** or **provide** Interface Builder plug-ins.  I have changed your question to reflect that, so it is more likely to be found by people using Google to search for similar things in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I know what I am looking for. Not all frameworks contain IB plugins. I am looking for a specific subset of frameworks, those which contain IB plugins. An IB-plugin without a framework is useless, therefore the framework part is assumed. I am NOT looking for regular old frameworks, so stop trying to change my question to that. Your additions only seem to be confusing people.

I have reported your post, hopefully moderators will be able to stop your obnoxious behavior.

Answer (score 0):

"Without a framework, what would you have to plug in to IB?"

Your words, not mine. Anyways, I'm done arguing this with you. Just remember that I can roll back for every time that you edit.

It's clear you have a lot of experience in this field, but instead of offering answers you decided to nitpick where there are no nits to pick.

Additionally, you have not "changed the question to refelct that," you have changed the question to a completely different question. I would have though that after four rollbacks you would relaize that you're doing more harm than good. Just stop, okay?

Comment: Why do you keep deleting comments and responding via the answers instead?  This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum; don't delete comments, add comments of your own.

Comment: Because up until your most recent edit, you repeatedly changed the question to mean something I was not asking. You previously used "&" instead of "with," which made the question sound like it was asking for both separately. Now, it's fine.

Comment: Additionally, your attitude as been nothing but condescending, quite nearly turning me off of StackOverlow and Cocoa programming entirely.

Comment: Your best bet is to never ask for help with Cocoa development. I've found that people like Chris Hanson are just waiting for the chance to tear you to shreds over minor semantic issues.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Chris Hanson is absolutely correct when he says that an Interface Builder plugin is useless without an accompanying framework. Interface Builder merely provides a graphical way to manage objects in a framework; without the framework itself, Interface Builder has nothing to manage.

However, I do think that there is a completely valid sort of Interface Builder plugin that wouldn't necessitate the installation of an accompanying framework, and that would be one that provides Interface Builder integration features for objects in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch which would otherwise appear as just generic objects.

For those of you who come to this page Google, please recognise the difference between Interface Builder plugins and frameworks: even the examples mentioned above work on frameworks (they could be Foundation, AppKit, UIKIt, etc.)